# Read text file (gcode) and use the coordinates

Tags: python

I'm trying to read a gcode file and use the coordinates on it. I have done this before, but now does not seem to work and I'm stuck.

Gcode example:

```
G1 F1300 X195 Y97.5 E62.70186
G0 F3000 X195 Y100
G1 F1300 X95 Y100 E125.40371
G0 F3000 X95 Y102.5
G1 F1300 X195 Y102.5 E188.10557
G0 F3000 X195 Y105
G1 F1300 X95 Y105 E250.80742
G0 F3000 X95 Y107.5
G1 F1300 X195 Y107.5 E313.50928
G0 F3000 X195 Y110
G1 F1300 X95 Y110 E376.21113
G0 F3000 X95 Y112.5
G1 F1300 X175 Y112.5 E426.37261
G0 F3000 X175 Y115
G1 F1300 X95 Y115 E476.5341
G0 F3000 X95 Y117.5
```

I can print and write to file all the lines and cells, but I need to get the value of `X`.

This is the code that I've used before to achieve it, but it doesn't work now. What I am missing?

```
with open("gcode.txt","r") as f:
    content = f.readlines()

for line in content:

    line = line.rstrip("\n")
    cells = line.split(" ")

    if line.startswith("G1"):
        x = float(cells[2].split("X")[1])
        print (x)
```

The error that I get is:

```
  x = float(cells[2].split("X")[1])

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: It means there is a line in your file that doesn't match the pattern

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Now I have detected it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

We have `line = "G1 F1300 X175 Y112.5 E426.37261"`

```
cells = line.split(" ")
```

Then, `cells = ["G1", "F1300", "X175", "Y112.5", "E426.37261"]`.

```
xcell = cells[2]
```

Then, `xcell = "X175"`.

```
split_x_cell = xcell.split("X")
```

Then, `split_x_cell = "['', '175']`.

```
split_x_cell[1] is the x-value.
```

It must be that one of the lines in your file doesn't fit the usual pattern.
Try running the following code and see what warning messages are printed:

```
import sys

with open("gcode.txt","r") as f:
    content = f.readlines()

for line in content:
    try:
        line = line.rstrip("\n")
        cells = line.split(" ")

        if line.startswith("G1"):
            cells = line.split(" ")
            xcell = cells[2]
            split_x_cell = xcell.split("X")
            x_val = float(split_x_cell[1])
            print(x)
    except IndexError:
        print(
            40*"#",
            "WARNING",
            "Incorrectly formatted line was omitted",
            repr(line),
            file=sys.stderr,
            sep = "\n",
        )
```

Comment: Yes, tehre were some lines that didn't correspond to the format. This probably didn't happened with the gcode that I've tested before when wrote the code the 1st time. Thank you Samuel